# ImageCapture API Alternative For Apple's Safari

Tags: safari, webrtc, image-capture

It has been a big pain for me to make the code I've written for Google Chrome to be able to run on Safari. You can't get more than one `userMedia` and now I ran into this problem where the `ImageCapture` API is not supported by Safari browsers. Since I want to take the photo from back camera, it's not really helpful if I just grab a frame from video element and paint it on a canvas.

Is there any solutions that I can use for this problem, I did some research but couldn't find anything that can solve my problem.

Comment: no-one? painting the stream on canvas is kind of a solution but the quality is way worse than the ImageCapture API

Comment: I'm also looking a solution for this. We're working on an openCV project where we require the camera's focal length and right now only chrome provides this metadata via ImageCapture API. Waiting for firefox & safari to support this API

Comment: A little late, but I came across this: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/imagecapture-polyfill